# socket.io with strange timestamp format (?)

Tags: socket.io, timestamp, url-parameters, data-formats

I see requests to socket.io containing parameter t to be like LZywzeV, LZz5lk7 and similar.

All examples that i found so far used second- or millisecond-based UNIX timestamps.

Has anyone ever seen a timestamp format like this? (It is not base64-encoded).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I started looking a site that uses Socket.io today, and got the same problem, trying to look for the protocol definition was useless.

I figured this format is something called [yeast](https://github.com/unshiftio/yeast)

TBH, really don't know why people invent this sort of things instead of use
`base64(timestamp.getBytes())` 
pseudocode instead.

A yeast decode algorithm in Python is as follow:

```
from datetime import datetime

a='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_'
b={a[i]: i for i in range(len(a))}

c=0
for d in "LZywzeV":
  c=c*64+b[d]

print(c)
print(datetime.fromtimestamp(c/1000))
```

The output of that code is:

```
1481712065055
2016-12-14 07:41:05
```

Comment: thanks for the explanation : do you have a code snippet for the function doing the other way round, ie. transforming regular datetimes into "yeast" datetimes ? thanks !

Answer (score 1):

to @jeremoquai:
It is easy, is matter of invert the algorithm:

```
def yeast(d):
  r=""
  while d!=0:
    r='0123456789ABCDEFGHIJKLMNOPQRSTUVWXYZabcdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyz-_'[d&63]+r
    d>>=6
  return r
```

so, if you run

```
yeast(1481712065055)
```

it returns LZywzeV